# having an issue in unity3d (free version) where an audio source is not being affected by reverb zones.. reverb bypass is disabled.. anyone?

Tags: gameaudio

Having an issue in unity3d (free version) where an audio source is not being affected by reverb zones.. reverb bypass is disabled.. anyone?

The source is having onehits run through it via a C# script. When I mute the source, the sounds stop, so I am fairly certain it is the correct source.

Comment: This has been [migrated to Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/91964/having-an-issue-in-unity3d-free-version-where-an-audio-source-is-not-being-aff) however it needs a bit more detail to be re-opened there.  Please go to the question on Game Development and supply the needed information.